# how to pass parameters in angularjs custom directive for function call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my code snippet -

```
<my-wizard
        on-finish="doFinish()"
```

I am calling on-finish from my-wizard's controller class.
It works and doFinish() gets invokes.
I want to pass some parameters to **doFinish()** from the directive controller.
What is the way for it?

This is my-wizard directive -

```
app.directive('myWizard', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {        
           onFinish: '&',
           ...
           }
        }
```

Comment: what is `on-finish`, a directive? Can you elaborate a little in your question on the order of operations? I guess it would be helpful to get more context on how it works and how you want it to work

Comment: Added it in the question detail.

Comment: This might help: https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/angularjs-understanding-directive-scope/

Answer (score 1):

Where is your onFinish() method getting called?

just pass some data to it in the shape of an object

```
onFinish({someData: data})
```

Then retrieve it using the same name of the object property:

```
function doFinish(someData) {
   console.log(someData)
}
```

The directive definition should also cater the passed argument:

```
<my-wizard
    on-finish="doFinish(someData)"
```